# Query displaying date format only instead of date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute a sql query in the date and time format but I am getting only date format as 26-Nov-15. Below is the query?

```
SELECT to_date((SYSTIMESTAMP - (20/1440)) ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM DUAL
```

what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `to_date()` on a `date` value - it makes no sense at all.

It first converts the input `date` into a `varchar` which is then converted back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

If you want to display the result in a formatted way use this:

```
SELECT to_char((SYSTIMESTAMP - (20/1440)) ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM DUAL
```

---

Unrelated, but: I prefer to use an `interval` to make an expression like the above readable:

```
SELECT to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - interval '20' minute,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM DUAL
```

In my opinion `interval '20' minute` is **much** easier to understand than `20/1440`

Comment: thanks, I want to know what does 20/1440 mean. I saw the query somewhere in the code.

Comment: I have explained that: it means 20 minutes, and your question proves my point that using `interval '20' minute` is the better way to write that